# Find company sector/industry from company name

Tags: java, nlp

I am working on a project where I need to find the industry of a company given the name of the company, e.g.:

For Amazon, the industry is Cloud Computing, AI, Consumer electronics and E-commerce (source, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_(company))).

I want to get these industry names programmatically (without crawling through wiki pages), what I tried is following:

- Downloaded all SIC codes from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Industrial_Classification)
- Tried to do a smart (tokenized) search with company's description and these names
- Collected first 3 closest matches

However, its giving so many false positives. Is there any way by which I can programmatically get company sector/industry from name?

Comment: I think there are some APIs which provide this informations, a quick search in google I get this one https://bigpicture.io/docs/enrichment/company/ and http://naics.codeforamerica.org/ and https://naicsapi.docs.apiary.io/#reference/conversions-between-naics-years-and-other-code-systems

Comment: another thing how many time you should to get this informations? one time per day, week, month, year or just one time?

Comment: More than one time per day, but I will cache this information so that I don't have to look it up again.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta can you let me know if you were successful with this requirement please, as I’m exactly in I need of the same. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful resource is patents registered by the company - the content of the patents might be more revelatory than the company web site.